# Explain the interaction between Jest, --verbose, and console.log

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to figure out how to use Jest properly. The interaction of Jest and console.log is very poorly documented (and apparently very inconsistent according to lots of tickets).

The Jest documentation is terrible.

When is console.log output supposed to show up? Always? Sometimes?

Seems to me the desired behavior would be for Jest to show console.log output for the tests that failed. I don't see anything about that in the documentation. What I do see is that console.log output seems to correlate somehow being either before or after tests.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default - `Jest` will print all console log results on the terminal which the tests are executed from. Instances when users do not see their logs are usually caused by the `silent` property being set to `true` in their config file or the `--silent` flag being added to their cli execution, which is not default `Jest` behaviour.

The `---verbose` flag causes the results of all individual `it` unit tests to be printed in the terminal (whereas by default the terminal would only print the names of the test suites that have passed and only unique unit tests (`it`) that have failed). Additionally each individual test will also display the length of time they took to execute *if they they take longer than 1ms*. Another interesting fact is that `--verbose` will also print logs of `console.log` executions that are run during the evaluation of a module (when a module is imported - e.g. a console statement that simply exists in the body of a javascript file or an implicitly invoked function) even though it is not used (e.g. the tests that uses it are not executed due to the `xdescribe` keyword in their test suite).

The ability to print console log results exclusively for failed tests is not present in `Jest`.